# Переменная "год" в титл страницы сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть плагин Yoast Seo позволяющий в титл страниц добавлять переменные %%currentyear%% и  %%currentmonth%%
А также добавлять свои переменные через functions.php

Задача выводить в титл месяц и год  (причём месяц будет постоянная величина, а год переменная) по следующей логике:
Например титл: "отдых в Болгарии в мае %переменная года%"
Переменная года должна рассчитываться по принципу, если месяц с этим названием уже прошёл в этом году, то выводим следующий год.
Если не прошёл или ещё идёт, выводим текущий год.

Как это правильно реализовать в functions.php

Буду очень благодарен помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указание этого плагина в вопросе только вводит в заблуждение, так как авторы эти подстановки (`%%currentyear%%`, `%%currentmonth%%`) реализуют не через `functions.php` и передать параметр в подстановки (что вам нужно) не получится.

Проще всего найти среди файлов вашей темы файл `functions.php`, добавить туда примерно такую функцию:

```
function validYearForMonth($month) {
    $month = intval($month);
    $currentMonth = date('n');
    $year = date('Y');

    if ($month < $currentMonth) {
        $year++;
    }

    return $year;
}
```

А теперь в файлах темы можете вызывать:

```
<?=validYearForMonth(5);?>
```

В параметре передаете номер месяца (начиная с 1). Так, в примере передан май. Для текущего момента (июнь 2016) будет возвращен 2017 год.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. А как сделать чтобы для ещё не закончившегося текущего месяца, выводился текущий год?

Comment: Так если передадите текущий месяц, то год будет тоже текущий. Следующий только для прошедших.